# Doctrine flush changes and free up memory

Tags: php, symfony, memory, memory-management, doctrine-orm

I'm experiencing problems working on a Symfony project with low memory limit. I need to create several entities, add them to another entity (entities are associated) and then flush changes to database. This happens in a `while` loop.

The problem is that sometimes the loop can't finish the whole cycle because the process crashes for memory exhausting. Of course I can't raise the memory limit.

I try to explain you better with some code...

### Entities structure

```
class Device
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Resource", inversedBy="devices",cascade={"persist", "refresh"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected $resources;

    public function addResource(Resource $resource)
    {
        if ($this->resources->contains($resource)) return;
        $this->resources->add($resource);
        $resource->addDevice($this);
    }
}

class Resource
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Device", mappedBy="resources")
     */
    protected $devices;

    public function addDevice(Device $device)
    {
        if ($this->devices->contains($device)) return;
        $this->devices->add($device);
        $device->addResource($this);
    }
}
```

### The loop

```
function doIt(Device $device) {
    while(...) {
        $res = new Resource(...);
        $device->addResource($res); // store $res in memory until end
    }
    $em->persist($device);
    $em->flush();
}
```

So the problem is that until the loop finishes, `$device` keeps in memory `Resource` objects and sometimes memory limit is reached.

### What I tried so far

```
function doIt(Device $device) {
   $i = 0;
   while(...) {
       $res = new Resource(...);
       $device->addResource($res);
       $i++;
       if ($i % 100 == 0) {
              $em->persist($device);
              $em->flush($device);
              $device->setResources(null); // free up Resources in memory
              $em->refresh($device); // Resources are not stored in memory
       }
   }
   $em->persist($device);
   $em->flush();
}
```

This works not that good even because I see memory raising anyway (probably caused then by Doctrine). Moreover there are a lot of entities and several associations between them, and checking results in database gives me something wrong (e.g. an Entity not persisted).

What would you do?

Comment: Is it used in data import or massive data manipulation?

Comment: Not so massive. I know that Doctrine is discouraged with import a lot of data, but I can't use plain SQL. The problem is the memory limit at 60M...

Comment: It's been a _long_ while, but did you ever find a sensible solution for this?

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich I didn't unfortunately

Answer (score 8):

There are a few things you can try to improve the situation:

Disable doctrine SQL logging mechanism in the setup stage of your import

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

Try calling a clear periodically (i do it after a batch of items is processed and flushed), but read the docs before because there may be side effects depending on your code

```
$this->entityManager->clear();
```

You already seem to be clearing all unused objects and variables you could also try calling a manual gc_collect_cycle in php

```
gc_collect_cycles();
```

If your import is executed with a symfony Command make sure you start it with the `--no-debug` flag

Worked fine with an import command within my project although it didn't achieve complete memory neutrality but the remaining leaks were negligible.
Maybe this can help in your case.

Comment: Doctrine logger is disabled and garbage collector should work good. I can't clear entityManager until the cycle finish, but the problem is that process crashes before the cycle finish. Anyway I don't need to improve the situation rather clear memory every X entites. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I never persist more then 50 entity after flush. Try to decrease $i to 50 or less. Maybe that help.

Comment: I can even flush entities every 10 iterations, the problem is that old data is still in memory, then the process is going to crash anyway...